# MacBook Pro keeps freezing randomly

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, performance

Since about two weeks ago, my MacBook Pro started freezing randomly. If iTunes is open, for example, the music keeps playing, but both the keyboard and the trackpad are not responding and it only recovers with a hard restart. I also noticed that it happens (not always, but sometimes) when I move it.

It’s an early 15" 2011 MacBook Pro with the latest version of Mavericks; original RAM and HDD.

How can I diagnose this issue?

I already checked the disk from recovery mode and says it’s fine. I also read the related questions here, but they don’t really apply.

Comment: If you connect a USB mouse/keyboard, does that work when it is frozen?
Sounds like it could be the USB connection to the built-in trackpad/keyboard that is faulty.

Comment: I haven’t tried, but I will.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is use [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) to test the RAM and the HDD as booting to Recovery Mode doesn't preform these tests nor does Disk Utility actually test the entire surface of the platters in the HDD.  It will also test other aspects of the hardware.  If all hardware tests pass then this issue is likely software related.  But the first step is to properly verify the hardware is okay.

Comment: @user3439894, all hardware tests passed. What should I do now?

Comment: First of all I doubt you did a through and complete hardware test in time since my first comment, however... Well, personally I'd clean build the system from a USB Installer after first making sure I have a complete Time Machine backup and another separate and redundant backup of my data on a different disk then the Time Machine backup.  I'd rather spend the time starting clean then spending the time troubleshooting the existing software build.

Comment: @user3439894 I did both the short one and the complete one. However, I also tried to connect an USB mouse and it doesn’t work. The mouse’s diode flashes red for half a second and then dies.

Comment: Check messages in Console.app. These may give a hint at the problem. If possible, have the Mac checked at the Apple Store. They have tests that are more specific than the ones you can run yourself. E.g. the 2011 has a known video card problem: https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/ The genius bar has a specific test to see if your Mac is affected.

Comment: @jksoegaard, no, it doesn’t—the diode flashes for half a second and then dies, so the mouse doesn’t work. I don’t have a bluetooth one at hand, so I can’t test it for now.

Comment: As @PierreBernard has suggested, you should take the Mac to nearest Apple Store for a check. It might have the GPU issue.

Answer (score 1):

After countless trips to the Apple Store and extensive testing by them, it turned out I have faulty memory DIMMs. At least that’s the only plausible explanation they reached after some 8 days of testing.

Comment: Have the DIMMs now been replaced? Does the freezing still occur? I've had freezes on my system, too, the last one just 10 minutes ago :{

Comment: @DictionaricsAnonymous, no, I haven’t changed them yet. I will update my answer once I do it.